# Why not attaching images after impoting using wp cli

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments, wp-cli

I want to move posts from one site to another, because of the big amount of posts I am trying with wp-cli import. The destination site also has huge amounts of posts, now when I am importing XML files. After importing the first batch I noticed images for each post are not attached to their own posts, and all images importing to the current date. And not importing main images, only resized image is imported. Featured images are fine.

```
wp import 2014-1.xml --authors=create
```

[image]